# Two player chess game in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

My source code can be seen on this url :https://forum.qt.io/topic/133078/raspbian-2-player-chess-game/52

There are 3 issues which need clarification :

How do I stop the streching of the last column and row of the chess board ?

How do I make the chess pieces transparent ?

How do I implement the mouse click event so that a square gets highlighted when the user presses the left mouse button ?

Comment: What are you trying to do in 16-th line? Did you mean     QPainter * ChessPiece = new QPainter();

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo

```cpp
    QPainter * ChessPiece - new QPainter();
```

becomes

```cpp
    QPainter * ChessPiece = new QPainter();
```